# Please check my DC / DC schematic. ST1S40

Tags: arduino, voltage, power, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I want to make a voltage down converter to power my controller (Atmega328P).

Input = 12V / Output = 5V (3A).
As a converter, I use [ST1S40](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/STMicroelectronics-ST1S40IDR_C126177.pdf).

My connection diagram

[image]

I took the circuit from datasheet, changed the values ​​of resistors R1, R2. The rest is unchanged. I did not find the connection scheme of this converter with an output voltage of + 5V.

Why did I choose him? To connect it does not require a lot of components. Unfortunately, I did not find other options.

Comment: Your EN(able) pin isn't wired?

Comment: A lot of regulators have the EN pin pulled up internally.  This one has it pulled down internally, so if you let it float your supply is disabled.

Comment: For clarity, it is good practice to draw power flowing in from the left and exiting from the right (as opposed to a symbol with pin-pin correspondence with footprint)

Comment: In addition to what @BBON said, here are [guidelines for drawing readable schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/28251/7036).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a 5 volt output then you need to recalculate R1 and R2. At the moment it will regulate to 6.8 volts and not 5 volts. This is because the FB pin needs to "see" 0.8 volts and with 5 volts at the output, it will see 0.588 volts and, as a result, the duty cycle will increase until it sees 0.8 volts and that occurs when Vout = 6.8 volts.

As others have mentioned in comments you need to have the enable input pulled high.

You also need to ensure that the thermal pad beneath your chip is connected to ground and that you have applied enough copper on the PCB to ensure the junction temperature does not exceed 150 degC. Read section 6.4 of the data sheet.

Section 6.5 also draws your attention to correct PCB layout and, at the bottom also reminds you about the thermal pad: -

> Thanks to the exposed pad of the device, the ground plane helps to
>   reduce the thermal resistance junction to ambient; so a large ground
>   plane, soldered to the exposed pad, enhances the thermal performance
>   of the converter allowing high power conversion.

Comment: 20 / (105 + 20) * 5 = 0.8 I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, that would work OK.

Comment: Then R1 (105k) and R2 (20k) have correct values?

Comment: You have calculated the values correctly.

Comment: Ok, is there any dependency on other elements (inductors and capacitors)? I collect it for the first time and do not really understand yet. :(

Comment: It turns out I placed the wrong resistor on the circuit, you were right. 150k i need to replace with 105k.

Comment: This is a simple question and answer site. You asked and I provided feedback. This site does not seek to provide an expose on the ins and outs of every detail of the chip. Read the data sheet is my advice and if you have a new question then please raise it. All the components chosen should be as those receommended in the data sheet. Any discepency or inconsistency would make a good question but you have to find it first.

Comment: @Алекс Гарисон no problem